# Создание исполняемого файла в hex-редакторе на Linux

Tags: ассемблер, ос, unix, linux

Можно ли на linux сделать так: создаёте файл в hex-редакторе и запускаете его как исполняемый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, можно. `chmod` вам в помощь. Но как по мне, так лучше просто осилить *nix ассемблер, это совсем несложно, причем он в разы понятнее виндовых ассемблеров.

p.s. Надеюсь, что вы, конечно, в курсе, какие форматы исполняемых файлов используются в linux.

Comment: Можете дать пример команды, как это сделать.

Comment: file.exe (наш файл созданный в hex-редакторе)
\# chmod +x file.exe
\# ./file.exe

Собственно и все

Answer (score 2):

Исполняемый файл какого типа двоичный или скрипт для shell? Если второе, то никаких особых проблем не вижу, с 1 вариантом теоретически возможно, а практически геморно, ибо нужно вручную заполнять кучу данных в структуре запуска, таких как точка входа, сегмент данных и т.д